# Jquery. Check if Div does not contain children with ID

Tags: jquery

My Html markup is as follows

[image]

How can i check with Jquery that the `divChatWindow` does not contain any of the child `li` id's ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="divChatWindow">
    <li>dsa</li>
    <li>ds</li>
</div>

<script>
    var el = $('#divChatWindow');
    var lis = el.find('li');

    alert(lis.length > 0 ? 'there are LIs' : 'No LIs there');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54jpzkgp/

Answer (score 0):

Try using......

```
if($("#divChatWindow").children().eq(0)==null)
     alert("Doesn't have childs");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divChatWindow li").is("*")
```

```js
console.log($("#divChatWindow1 li").is("*"), $("#divChatWindow2 li").is("*"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divChatWindow1">
  <li>1</li>
</div>
<div id="divChatWindow2">2
</div>
```